# Oracle Apex Ora 01403 no data found

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

I have one small question. How to resolve this problem.

First, I have this code below and he give error Ora 01403 no data found. This code was debugged and I find when he give this error. This place was marked.

Second, my question is How I can modify this code?

Thirdly, how I can take only one row from the cursor? I know that command "fetch" store data for new row in variable with %rowtype

Fourthly, main task is need to store data from cursor in different tables with diffrent FK  For this task was wroten this code. If anyone have Idea how to do this I wiil be greate to see solution or explanation how to resolve this "question". Thanks.

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR c_data IS
    SELECT td.*
    FROM ddf td
    WHERE td.col1 IS NOT NULL
        AND td.col2 IS NOT NULL
        AND td.col3 IS NOT NULL
        AND td.col4 IS NOT NULL
        AND td.col5 IS NOT NULL
        AND td.col6 IS NOT NULL
        AND td.col7 IS NOT NULL
        OR td.col8 IS NOT NULL
        OR td.col9 IS NOT NULL
        OR td.col10 IS NOT NULL;

    c_id            NUMBER;
    r_number        NUMBER;
    ed     NUMBER;
    nid  NUMBER;
    ssd       NUMBER;
    iiy number := :p13ns;
BEGIN

    FOR i IN c_data LOOP
        c_id := 0;
        r_number := 0;
        r_number := random_number();
        c_id := get_cd(i.col5);

        INSERT INTO rrree ( 
            efn, eii, ec, edd, tei, eln, emn, ebd, eid, eiid
        ) VALUES (
            i.col1, i.col8 || i.col9, c_id, to_date(sysdate, 'MM/DD/YYYY'),
                CASE
                    WHEN i.col8 IS NOT NULL THEN (
                            SELECT tei FROM vre WHERE tei = 1 ) ELSE (
                            SELECT tei FROM vre WHERE tei = 2 )
                END, i.col3, i.col2, to_date(i.col4, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), to_date(i.col6, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), to_date(i.col7, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
        );

        COMMIT;

/* Second call for this select get error Ora-01403 no data found. */
        SELECT DISTINCT( dii ) INTO ed
        FROM vrt
        WHERE upper(efn) LIKE upper(i.col1)
            AND upper(eln) LIKE upper(i.col3)
            AND upper(emn) LIKE upper(i.col2)
            AND ROWNUM = 1;
/* end Second call for this select get error Ora-01403 no data found. */

        SELECT DISTINCT( isd ) INTO nid
        FROM vri
        WHERE isd = iiy
            AND ROWNUM = 1;

        INSERT INTO rrre ( 
            cal_id, dii
        ) VALUES ( 
            1, ed
        );

        COMMIT;

        SELECT DISTINCT( sd ) INTO ssd
        FROM rrre
        WHERE dii = ed
            AND ROWNUM = 1;

        INSERT INTO rrrs ( 
            sid, sssi, sns, sts, sids, va, cdc, dii, sd, disv, isd
        ) VALUES ( 
            to_date(sysdate, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), nid, r_number, to_date(sysdate + 5, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 1, 1, 1, ed, ssd, to_date(sysdate, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), nid
        );

        COMMIT;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: First of all you just need to decide what do you want to assign to ed if there is no rows satisfied your conditions (predicates `upper(efn) like upper(i.col1)...`)

Comment: I want to get just one record  from the table. (i.col1, i.col2, i.col3) this is the  parameters from selected row in for loop. If no data he must be not executed